# Changing chrome notification settings manually

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to change the notification settings without doing it manually in chrome settings? Is there any api for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the [`contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings) extension API:

```
chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set({
  primaryPattern: 'match pattern',
  setting: 'allow|block|ask',
});
```